# react-router: whole DOM disappears when inserting NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm new to react and trying to manage the navigation in my web app with react-router.
I must be doing something wrong though, because my whole DOM is disappearing. Everything's fine while I set up the router:

**Container.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SideBar from "./sidebar/SideBar";
import Pagina from "./content/Pagina";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    NavLink
} from 'react-router-dom'
import NavRoutes from "./NavRoutes";

class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="MyLearningContainer" className ="container-fluid">
                <SideBar/>
                <Pagina/>
                <Router>
                    {NavRoutes}
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Container;
```

**NavRoutes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from "./content/Dashboard";
import Utenti from "./content/Utenti";

const navRoutes = (
    <Route path="/" component= {Dashboard}>
        <Route path="utenti" component = {Utenti} />
    </Route>
);

export default navRoutes;
```

The problem arises when I make my SideBarItem generate a `<NavLink>` inside its usual `<li>`:

**SideBarItem.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    NavLink
} from 'react-router-dom'


const defaultClass = {
    color: '#00338D',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
};

const activeClass = {
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#428bca',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
};

class SideBarItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                <NavLink to={("/" + this.props.title).toLowerCase()}>
                    <span className={this.props.glyph}></span> {this.props.title}
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

SideBarItem.defaultProps = {
    title: 'Undefined',
    glyph: 'glyphicon-home'
}


export default SideBarItem;
```

When I save this, the whole DOM just disappears and nothing gets rendered anymore!

---

**Update**

I edited the Container.js so that SideBar is now a child of Router.

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="MyLearningContainer" className="container-fluid">
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <SideBar/>
                        {NavRoutes}
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now the DOM renders just fine, but clicking on the NavLink won't make the route change: it stays on Dashboard...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? From a quick glance, if `SideBarItem` is a child of `SideBar` it looks like your NavLink components are outside of the <Router> component because `SideBar` is a sibling of <Router>. They would need to be children of the <Router> component .

Comment: No, I wasn't getting any error in the console... Thanks though! I didn't know that links to routes had to be inside the router itself, but it's quite obvious now that I think about it. 
Now the DOM renders, but clicking on the NavLinks won't make the routes appear (see post update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the router working!

Following thenormalsquid's advice, I edited the Container.js so that SideBar became a child of Router.

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="MyLearningContainer" className="container-fluid">
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <SideBar/>
                        {NavRoutes}
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then I edited NavRoutes.js, that wasn't pointing at the right links.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from "./content/Dashboard";
import Utenti from "./content/Utenti";

const navRoutes = (
    <div>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component= {Dashboard}/>
        <Route path="/utenti" component = {Utenti} />
        <Route path="/corsi" component = {Corsi} />
    </div>
);

export default navRoutes;
```

Now everything works fine and the page changes when you click on the sidebar links!