# DOM disappearing when replacing anchor tags with React Link components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, routes, frontend

I am new to working on the frontend. I'm learning how to use React and react-router-dom library. The program renders without a problem normally. The problem lies when I try to add a Link component from the React library. When I do this, the DOM is no longer displayed.

```
import React from "react"
import {Routes, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom"
import Mflix from "./components/mflix.js"

function App(){

return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a href="/mflix" className="navbar-brand"> {/*href links to "/mflix" route */}
         Mflix Reviews
        </a>
        <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item">
           <Link to={"/mflix"} className="nav-link">
            Movies
           </Link>
          </li>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
)

}
```

[This SO forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267295/react-router-whole-dom-disappears-when-inserting-navlink) has a similar problem, except they created a class for their app, and I'm trying to keep it as a function for now.

If I replace the code:

```
<Link to={"/mflix"} className="nav-link">
    Movies
 </Link>
```

with

```
<a href="/mflix"m className="nav-link">
  Movies
</a>
```

The DOM renders fine, buT I want to use Link because it doesn't force my page to refresh every time.

Edit: I read that instead of passing a JS expression to the to `<Link to{"/mflix"}/>` I should pass a string `<Link to"/mflix"/>`. However, [the documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) says that if the link uses a path name, then it should be passed to `to=` as an object, and not a string. IN any case, I tried the suggestion, but the code still returns a blank page.

Edit: This is what the web console has to say about the  component:

```
he above error occurred in the <Link> component:

LinkWithRef@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37314:9
li
div
nav
div
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40:72

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the DOM disappears, there is an issue in your code. I'm guessing it has to do with this "Mflix" import. Bring up the console and see what it says.

Comment: Hey, I added the output from my web console. I agree it is probably a problem in my import statement, but I don't think it comes from `import Mflix` I think there's something wrong with my `react-router-dom`, because the DOM disappears when I use components form that library (Link, Routes, Route, etc)